# How to do an xforms:insert without the need of xforms:delete at the end?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, xsltforms, xforms-betterform

```html
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
    <xf:insert nodeset="instance('subInstance')/type" origin="instance('defaultType')/type"/>
</xf:action>
```

I want to populate an instance based on another one. I can do this using xf:insert as shown above.

However, I realised that the instance 'subInstance' must contain an empty type element before starting the xf:inserts.

```html
<subInstance>
  <type/>
</subInstance>
```

So after all the xf:inserts, I need do the following to delete the first empty one:

```html
<xf:delete nodeset="instance('subInstance')/type" at="1" />
```

Is there something wrong with this method or is there a way I can insert directly without an initial empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two answers:

### You don't really need an initial type element

Your original instance can simply be:

```
<subInstance/>
```

And then you can insert *into* the `subInstance` element with:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
    <xf:insert
        context="instance('subInstance')"
        origin="instance('defaultType')/type""/>
</xf:action>
```

Using `context` without `nodeset` or `ref` says that you want to insert *into* the node pointed to by `context`.

### You can still do what you want but with XForms 2.0 support

If you want to keep the original nested `type` element, you could write this:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
    <xf:insert
        nodeset="instance('subInstance')"
        origin="
            xf:element(
                'subInstance',
                instance('defaultType')/type
            )
        "/>
</xf:action>
```

1. By targeting the root element of the destination instance, the entire instance will be replaced. This is already the case with XForms 1.1.
2. With the `origin` attribute's use of the [`xf:element()`](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XPath_Expressions_Module#The_element.28.29_Function) function from XForms 2.0, you can dynamically create an XML document rooted at `subInstance` and containing only the `type` elements from the `defaultType` instance.

To make this even more modern, you would replace `nodeset` with `ref`, as `nodeset` is deprecated in XForms 2.0:

```
<xf:action ev:event="xforms-model-construct">
    <xf:insert
        ref="instance('subInstance')"
        origin="
            xf:element(
                'subInstance',
                instance('defaultType')/type
            )
        "/>
</xf:action>
```

Comment: Thanks. The first answer (the context) is what I was looking for.